# Find Exact match in a string- C#

Tags: c#

How can I search for an exact match in a string? For example, If I had a string with this text:

```
string ClientName = "Sunny Mrs Cool";
string[] stringArray = { "Mr", "Ms", "Dr", "Mrs" };
    
foreach (string x in stringArray)
{                               
   if (ClientName.Contains(x))
   {}
}
```

And I want to search for "Mrs", I only want to get the exact match, not the other. I tried Contains and IndexOf methods, but they also give me "Mr".
Some of the string has Ms or Dr or Mr.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO!  You *can* split your words and then compare... Have you searched on SO for similar questions with answers? There's definitely more than one way to do this.

Comment: I'm no regex wizard but something like `\b(?i)(mr|ms|dr|mrs)\b` should give you a match when the string contains one of the words in the list and you can find which one it was via the capture group. You can also dynamically build the regex via `var regex = $"\b(?i)({string.Join('|',searchTerms)})\b";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without adding headaches / regex you could use Linq pretty easily:

```
string ClientName = "Sunny Mrs Cool";
    
string[] stringArray = { "Mr", "Ms", "Dr", "Mrs" };
    
var results = ClientName.Split(' ').ToList().Where(x => stringArray.Contains(x));
    
Console.WriteLine(results.Single());  // result is "Mrs"
```

You could then do logic based off of the results instead:

```
if (results.Any())
{
    process(results.first());
}
else
{
   //no valid result!
}
```

Or if enumerating the array, and finding the match matters. The above code with a loop could work too:

```
var result = results.First();
foreach(var x in stringArray)
{
   if (x == result)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"{ClientName} contains: {result}");
       // Writes "Sunny Mrs Cool contains: Mrs"
   }
}
```

Comment: OP wants to match, not see if it exists/contained in a word...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Yes, I sense a bit of an XY problem with the code posted. If he has a match at all then this works if that's what he wants: `if (x == clientName.Abbreviation)` essentially. Although adding a more literal == might help answer the question as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex for that. Your Regex pattern could be like:

```regex
\b(Mr|Ms|Dr|Mrs)\b
```

- The `\b` means *Word boundary*
- The `|` means *OR*.

So, this regex will match `Mr`, `Ms`, `Dr`, or `Mrs` on word boundaries.

---

Edit:

The problem with your code is `Mr` being a subset of `Mrs`. So, any string contains `Mrs` it will also contain `Mr`. Because you search for `Mr` first, you will always find it before `Mrs`.

Searching on word boundaries solves this issue in an easy way.

---

Here is the C# code for using Regex for this task:

```cs
string clientName = "Sunny Mrs Cool";
string[] stringArray = { "Mr", "Ms", "Dr", "Mrs" };
string pattern = $"\\b({string.Join("|", stringArray)})\\b"; // or simply just "\b(Mr|Ms|Dr|Mrs)\b"
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(clientName, pattern).Groups[1].Value); // prints "Mrs"
```

Comment: How does this get applied to the OP code? Also why use `Regex`, is the user using it? What did the OP do wrong in the first place? You missed these important questions when answering IMHO.

Comment: @Youssef13 thanks, how do you apply your suggestion and why use `Regex`?